# AngularJS "localStorage.getItem" is null in $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, token

I have an angular `$resource` for login and getting user's info. The login sends the username and password to server and gets a Bearer token. In the `success` function of `User.login` the token is stored in `localStorage`. In `getEmail`, I'm including the token in header to the user's email address.

The problem is, the first time `getEmail` is called in controller, `$window.localStorage.getItem('TK')` evaluates to `null` but if I refresh the page then it works correctly. All of the subsequent requests to the server that have the token included work as expected. What could cause this?

Not to mention, `getEmail` is called way after login and I have confirmed that the token is present in `localStorage` before the `getEmail` is called.

```
angular.module('authentication')
    .factory('User', function ($resource, $window) {
        return $resource('/login', {}, {
            login: {
                method: 'POST'
            },

            getEmail: {
                url: '/user',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': "Bearer " + $window.localStorage.getItem('TK')
                }
            }
        });
    })
```

In response to @ comment:
My controller looks like this:

```
angular
        .module('app.mymodule', ['ngReource', 'authentication')
        .controller('myCtrl', mymodule);

    mymodule.$inject = ['User', '$window'];

    function mymodule(User, $window) {

        // THIS PRINTS THE TK IN CONSOLE CORRECTLY
        console.log($window.localStorage.getItem("CHTOKEN"));

        // THIS IS UNAUTHORIZED CUZ TK IS NULL
        User.getEmail({}, function(data){
                console.log('set the email');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just to know if that's an angular issue, what happens if you use the regular `window` instead of `$window`?

Comment: @floribon, just tried it. Same problem.

Comment: So this is not related to angular. Somehow you don't have the data in your localStorage even if you think you do. Can you log `window.localStorage.getItem('TK')` even before running any angular code? If it is null, then angular will not help.

Comment: @floribon, I have updated my question. I have logged the token just before calling the `getEmail` and it correctly prints it to the console. So the Token is actually there. I can even see it in my FF DevTool.

Comment: You are first logging the `CHTOKEN ` item. Then in your getEmail function you are checking for `TK`. These are two different items, so nothing shows that TK does exist before the call to getEmail. If it still does, it means somewhere you erase the value, either with `localStorage.removeItem` or `localStorage.clear`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the resource definition is provided at the time of creation (before you have saved a token).

You can either add a general [request interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) to the `$httpProvider` so all requests are covered or change your `getEmail` action's `header` to use a function so it is evaluated at run time, eg

```
headers: {
    'Authorization': function() {
        var token = $window.localStorage.getItem('TK');
        return token ? 'Bearer ' + token : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution!  It's easy to forget the factories are instantiated at birth and the error messages can hide the true problem!