# AngularJs optional header param (token)

Tags: angularjs, authentication, token, angular-resource

My app is using token based auth, but a guest can get data too. So for requesting data, I decided to use ngResource lib and write a factory for it.
First, the auth controller gets a token from the server and places it to localstorage. After that $place proceeds to the home page where the home controller requests data through Home factory.
My problem is that if I use guest mode and then authorize with user data, my app can't add the token header to $resource object.
After reload page everything is working properly, but I need do it without reloading. Here is my factory code

```
.factory('placeResource', ['$resource','$window', function($resource,$window) {
    var get_token = function(){
        if ($window.localStorage.token){
            return 'token '+$window.localStorage.token
        }
    };
    return $resource("/api/:resourceName/place/:placeId",
        { resourceName: '@_resourceName', placeId: '@placeId'},
        {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
            headers: { 'Authorization': get_token() }}
        }
    );
}]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS "localStorage.getItem" is null in $resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444268/angularjs-localstorage-getitem-is-null-in-resource)

Comment: well im using promise so im sure redirect to home page happening after token placing