# Angular Factory, Service, and Controller not Working Together with $Resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have an Angular service that's just a setter and getter for a variable I need to pass between controllers:

```
  var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
    .service('userToken', function() {
      var userTokenProp;
      return {
        getter: function() {
          return userTokenProp;
        },
        setter: function(value) {
          userTokenProp = value;
        }
      };
    })
```

Then a bit further down I'm trying to use $resource in a factory based on the value of that token.  There's another almost identical factory that is able to set the token, but this latter factory can't get or use the token.  I also need to send the token into the header while making the request.  The code I have for that is this, a form I settled on after trying any number of other ways to pass the data into the factory and to set the header in $resource:

```
.factory("apiQueryProfileFactory", function($resource, userToken) {
      console.log("token: " + userToken.getter());
      var uToken = userToken.getter();
      var resource = $resource('http://localhost:3001/lsportal/api/v1/profile/:path', {}, {
        get: {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {'token': uToken}
        },
      });
      return resource;
    });
```

And then from the controller (which, yes, is passed the factory and service):

```
apiQueryProfileFactory.get({path:'role'}, function(data) {

})
```

Just don't get what I'm missing, and I've been over and over it for a while now!

Comment: Also, that console.log in the factory fires when the app first loads!  But there are simple a chain of factories and services following the initial "app" declaration, but maybe the problem is that I've got things string together wrong.  If anyone suspects this I'm glad to post the entire declaration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS "localStorage.getItem" is null in $resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444268/angularjs-localstorage-getitem-is-null-in-resource)

Comment: Mmm...not really no.  Other than fact that we're both using something called "token" we're describing somewhat different problems.  The other poster is also not attempting to call an angular service, he's trying to pass data pulled from localstorage into the header.

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer? The problem is the same; your `$resource` action headers are static and `uToken` is undefined when your factory is created. Use the function version of the header value (you could actually just set it to `headers: { token: userToken.getter }`)

Comment: I don't really hate it when I'm wrong, but I really hate it when I'm wrong on SO.  Thanks Phil!  Post if you want answer points or else I'll take it down.

Comment: It's ok to just close it as a duplicate. It provides more SEO for StackOverflow without cluttering the answer-space. If you feel like awarding points, vote up the dupe question and answer which may or may not be mine ;)